# Heroku using old dependencies?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Basically I've made an API which is using a nodejs dependency. (tiktok scraper)
The old version of this dependency was bugged, but a new version has been released.

I updated it and re pushed to Heroku.
It's working fine locally but still buggy on Heroku.

I've checked the version of the dependency used on Heroku and it seems to be the last one.

I even created new Heroku apps with the last version of the dependency but not working.

I've already tried to heroku restart, purge cache, etc..

I don't know what's the problem ?

```
const TikTokScraper = require("tiktok-scraper");
var express = require("express");
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();
app.listen(port, () => {
  app.get("/user", async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = await getUser(req.query.username);
    res.json(result);
  });
});

async function getUser(username) {
  const userObject = await TikTokScraper.user(username);
  const userInfo = userObject.collector[0];


  const name = userInfo.authorMeta.nickName;
  const image = userInfo.authorMeta.avatar;
  const followers = userInfo.authorMeta.fans;
  const following = userInfo.authorMeta.following;
  const numVideos = userInfo.authorMeta.video;

  let numViews = 0;
  let numLikes = 0;
  let numComments = 0;
  let numShares = 0;
  userObject.collector.forEach((video) => {
    numViews += video.playCount;
    numLikes += video.diggCount;
    numComments += video.commentCount;
    numShares += video.shareCount;
  });

  const engagementRate = parseFloat(
    (
      ((numLikes + numComments + numShares) / numVideos / followers) *
      100
    ).toFixed(2)
  );

  const finalUserObject = {
    name,
    image,
    followers,
    following,
    numVideos,
    numViews,
    numLikes,
    numComments,
    numShares,
    engagementRate,
  };
  console.log("FINAL = ", finalUserObject);
  return finalUserObject;
}
```

This is working fine locally, but when I push it to Heroku, userInfo is null.
You can try the app locally like this : http://localhost:3000/user?username=boobaofficial

Comment: Can you state and elobrate what is your problem with node js in your project

Comment: I've just edited it

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is node.js version

go check your node.js version by

```
node -v
```

then add your version to your package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
}
```

then deploy to heroku again, heroku will read your package.json and specify node version you use :)

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working even after specifying node version to package.json